# Safely aborting threads in a ThreadList

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

A threadlist is being used so threads can be aborted at the user's request.  Thus far, I ported some code from killing processes (also based on removing list items safely), but it is not aborting any of the threads.  Using the try catch alone inside a loop from 0 To Threadlist.Count will abort the threads but will also result in an exception related to use of a list whose elements have been removed.  Is there anything that I am doing wrong in the following code:

```
        For x As Integer = threadList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim tid As String = threadList(x).ManagedThreadId
            For Each t As Thread In threadList
                If tid = t.ManagedThreadId.ToString Then
                    Try
                        t.Abort()
                        threadList.RemoveAt(x)
                    Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
                        'ex.ToString()
                    End Try
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove an item from the list used in a For Each loop. Get the thread you want to remove and then remove it.

```
        Dim threadToRemove As Thread = Nothing

        ' First, find the thread to remove
        For Each t As Thread In threadList
            If tid = t.ManagedThreadId.ToString Then
                threadToRemove = t
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ' Then, remove the thread
        If threadToRemove IsNot Nothing Then
                Try
                    t.Abort()
                    threadList.Remove(threadToRemove)
                Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
                    'ex.ToString()
                End Try
        End If
```

By splitting your logic it will be ok. You can then put those two pieces in method if you want.

I don't know if this piece of code will fix your problem but I hope you get the idea. Looping your threadList twice will just remove all thread in a complicated way.

Comment: Since you used threadtoremove = t, wouldn't the removeat() want an integer index value for the list position.  Right now, the removeat() would be using a thread as the index number?

Comment: @wrtsvkrfm sorry, I changed it to Remove(). But I hope the idea behind the post will help. I can't test the code.